# Error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied, when attempting to run server on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**I am currently unable to run my server locally. I am using Postgres database, the Ruby on Rails framework, and I am running this all on Mac OS X.**

**Specific issue:** After running rails s in the terminal, and opening localhost:3000 in my browser, I get an error- fe_sendauth: no password supplied

**What I have done so far:**

- I have gone into my pg_hba.conf file and verified that the Method for all the fields was 'trust' (has been trust all along, file is unchanged)
- I have researched many related questions on stack overflow and answers have been in regards to changing the Method field within this file and then reloading the configuration. I don't believe this applies to my situation here, as mine have already been set to 'trust'
- I have looked over the documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auth-methods.html and here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html and was unable to find a solution for my problem.

**Side Notes:**

Additionally, I had no problem running it locally when I was last working on this project less than a month ago. I had never run into this error before.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set a password for your Postgres user recently?

Comment: You're connecting to a different database instance than you think you are, I guess. If auth is trust, postgres wouldn't be asking for a password. Alternately, maybe there are other `pg_hba.conf` entries in the file too?

Comment: I believe I only set my postgres password once and that was before starting the project. I'm not sure how I could be connecting to another instance of the database, as I have not changed my database.yml file at all. Could have turning off postgres when I wasn't using it cause this sort of thing to happen? Also, could you elaborate on having other pg_hba.conf entries in the file? I was only able to find one file on my computer named pg_hba.conf and there were a total of three fields that I could modify. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check config/databases.yml and make sure you have a password set for the environment you are running (development, test, production). Particularly for the production env the default is

```
password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

which is effectively blank unless you set the environment variable.

Comment: I saw that my development environment in my database.yml file didn't    have a password set. (As this was never previously required) . 
I added-    

`password: <%= ENV['LISTENHERE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>`    
 (although I'm not sure where I would set this environment variable) . 
  
I also tried setting password to be my actual password to see if that would  fix it (rather than calling a variable) .   
`password: <%= "*******************" %>   `   

I am still receiving the same error. Is it possible to force it to not ask for a  password within the development environment at all?